# How to install AMD drivers on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS?

Tags: drivers, 64-bit, amd-graphics

I have **AMD Radeon x1600 Series** graphics card, I installed the official driver file from AMD website and ran it but it just created some files then deleted them, no drivers were installed. Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer. There are 2 versions that could be called the latest.

Comment: done @David its 20.04.1 LTS